# How do I configure Raspbian to work like TAILS?

Tags: tails

As there isn't a Tor Browser Bundle or TAILS version packaged for the Raspberry Pi, I would like to setup a standard Raspbian install to work as closely as possible to, if not exactly like TAILS.

So besides
    -Changing the default pi password
    -Disabling root & pi login
    -Installing tor and configuring the browser's proxy to pass all traffic through tor.
   -Disabling unnecessary programs/services that might be listening/waiting for a connection.
   -Spoofing the NIC MAC Addresses.
what else can I do to configure Raspbian to work more like TAILS?

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/GouveaHeitor/nipe) can theoretically do it for you but I haven't personally tried it. If you don't know how to troubleshoot networking issues, you might now want to just run Firefox + Tor to make your own Tor Browser.

If you've got the tech savvy to try it, first start off with just Firefox + Tor on your RPI. From another computer on your network, set up Wireshark and look at the kind of traffic that the RPI is generating, especially DNS requests. You shouldn't see any coming from Firefox but you should see some coming from things like apt-get when you do updates/installs. After you set up nipe, keep testing. You should stop seeing anything that isn't going through Tor. If you do, make sure that you set it up correctly and if it still happens then there is a problem and you should put in a bug with them.